# ¿Cómo puedo crear una relación uno a muchos sobre un mismo modelo en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

TEngo un modelo "Categorías" con el cual necesito crear categorías dentro de una categoría, esto sería una relación de uno a muchos con el mismo modelo, yo he hecho estas relaciones pero con otros modelos no entiendo bien como crear esta relación, ¿como podría crearla o con qué información podría lograrlo?

Comment: Es casi igual a cualquier otra relación, checa la [Guía de Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), la cual muestra un ejemplo claro.

Comment: Hola amigo, buen día! Tienes que crear una migración para agregar el campo otra_categoria_id o como le quieras llamar a la misma tabla categorías de la siguiente manera. t.references :otra_categoria, foreign_key: { to_table: :categorias } Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una referencia a la categoria "padre" de cada categoria. Por ejemplo con esta migracion.

```
class CrearCategorias < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categorias do |t|
      t.references :supercategoria, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

En el modelo debes definir ambas relaciones, de uno a muchos y de muchos a uno consigo mismo, indicando que la clase a usar es la misma, aunque no lo sean los nombres de las relaciones. Asi cada categoria puede tener muchas subcategorias apuntando a ella.

```
class Categoria < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategorias, class_name: "Categoria",
                          foreign_key: "supercategoria_id"

  belongs_to :supercategoria, class_name: "Categoria"
end
```

Espero que esto sea util.